# "UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 1" strange keyboard behaviour

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwindow

This code in the `appDelegate` makes my app behave strange

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 1;
    return YES;
}
```

When hiding the keyboard from the function `[myTextView resignFirstResponder]` I'm getting my keyboard disappearing under the view, not sliding down as it should.

What is the best way to change this? Why does `UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 1` mess up all the app structure?

**EDIT:**

What I'm trying to do is create a view on top of the `statusBar`. Is setting `UIWindowLevelStatusBar + 1` in the `appDelegate` a wrong way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard also exists in a window (everything on the screen does) and that window has a level lower than your window's.

Why are you setting your window level so high? If you tell us what you're trying to accomplish, we may be able to suggest an alternate approach.

Comment: Check out my edit. Maybe we can somehow put a keyboard on a higher level?

Comment: But *why* are you trying to do that? What's the actual goal here?

Comment: Creating a view that can cover the statusBar to display something on it *while* sustaining the normal keyboard sliding/disappearance behaviour.

Comment: Yes, I got that, but *why* are you trying to do that?

Comment: To have the ability to put some content on top of the statusBar and when this content disappears - I want to have a statusBar there. Overlay it or something. Anyway, **right now** I'm trying to find the fix for the keyboard problem. Can it be solved?

Comment: Not really, no. You're going about it the wrong way. If no part of the status bar is going to be visible, then just hide the status bar and place your window at `Normal + 1` to ensure it's above your main window. If some part of the status bar is going to be visible, you're going to have a huge headache because the arrangement of the status bar elements varies widely between devices, carriers, configurations, time of day, the user's preferences, etc.

Comment: Where should all this process be handled? in the appDelegate or somewhere else?

Comment: That depends on the structure of your app. Personally, I'd create a custom `StatusBarReplacementController` class or some such that owns the window and handles the display/hiding of it (and make it a subclass of `UIViewController` so I can use a XIB for the layout.) The app delegate would then presumably own an instance of that class and expose accessors/methods as needed, but the actual logic of showing/hiding the custom interface would be encapsulated in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

Man, i know this is 2 year old but here it goes:

Works on iOS 7 and 8, not tested on 9 betas.

I'm adding a ticker to the status bar. Yeah i know apple does not like it, but users have the choice to use it there ore somewhere else.

In app Delegate, when you want to hide the contents of the status bar (carrier, hour, battery), you call:

```
self.window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar+1;
```

Ok

The problem was to figure out how to get the contents back, right ? That was my problem too. Here it is:

```
self.window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar-1;
```

Bye

Answer (score 0):

Hide the status bar and set frame for navigation bar simple.

```
CGRect statusFrame = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, statusFrame.size.height, 320,46);
[[AppDelegate instance].window addSubview:statusView];
```